# What is social science and discussion about Type II error preference?

Tags: econometrics, type-i-and-ii-errors, social-science

Today, my senior lecturer in economics and finance class teaching about laws impact companies' operation told us one sentence
"**Also keep in mind that in (at least social) science, we care (try to avoid) about Type II (making a claim on some new finding while it is actually not true), more than Type I error (rejecting some new findings while it is actually true).** "

From [this link](https://esrc.ukri.org/about-us/what-is-social-science/#:%7E:text=Social%20science%20is%2C%20in%20its,influence%20the%20world%20around%20us.), the definition of social science is:
"Social science is, in its broadest sense, the study of society and the manner in which people behave and influence the world around us."

I have two questions:

1> Based on this definition, why economics relating to social science, and what is other than social science?

2> Why he can make the claim above regarding Type I and Type II in social science?

Comment: I think your professor was making a sweeping generalization on the -culture- of economics/social science disciplines (i.e., what people in those fields value). Otherwise, it's not clear there is a logical link between the definition of economics/social science and one needing to value type I vs type II errors.

Comment: Hi @Cat, does the specific topic "**laws impact companies' operation**" relates to valuing type I and type II errors?

Comment: "Social science" is a contrast to "natural science" (which is sometimes divided between "physical science" and "life science").  The aversion to Type II errors is general, and is related to seeing sins of commission as worse than sins of omission.

Comment: For question 1 what is required is hardly statistical expertise. In other words, it doesn't really belong here. Regarding question 2, surely the part about Type I errors is misleading, as nobody should "reject" anything in case a statistical test doesn't reject the null hypothesis.